# How can I solve this python problem?[django]

Tags: python, django

Why cannot I migrate.  It says assertion error. [Here is the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGpNK.png)

```
# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id= models.AutoField()
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="" )
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="" )
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop/images', default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

Comment: `product_id` is causing the error as it is an `AutoField`. Django automatically creates a id for every object which is an auto field. So, if you want to create an attribute `id` for your model, use another type instead of `models.AutoFied` such as `models.UUIDField` or any other

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield. See this for reference

Comment: If you want your `product_id` to be your `Primary key` you can set it by using `models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`

Comment: Include the error message into the question as formatted text. Links and images should never be used to include core information, unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It conflicted product_id field within Product Table. Or if you want to create product_id as your primary key in your product table just write `models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`